# Coding r in Jupyter Lab (irkernel) - Using stringr package: The str_view() function fails

Tags: r, stringr, jupyter-irkernel

Can anyone use the str_view() function in Jupyter Lab?

Whenever the str_view() function is used, the output returns only a partial white screen and the function returns no values.  No other stringr functions have any noticeable issues. This str_view() function does perform as expected in R studio.

Tried a work-around using that nifty Jupyter feature, "Create New View for Outputs"  in attempts to output that partial failed-display But then things get really screwy.   That New View window grows continuously larger, becomes unmanageable,  becomes unstable, then crashes Jupyter.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
med <- as.matrix(read.csv("med.csv"))
med

str_length(med)
str_match(med, "Pill")

str_view(med, "Pill")
```

To the best of my knowledge, this is a standard install and configuration of python, Jupyter, and the Irkernel.

Therefore it would be nice to know if others are having a similar issue when using the str_view() function with the Irkernel, or whether it's the setup on this particular PC.

Screen print is below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's to do with the JupyterLab theme. Some things still don't display too well in JupyterLab's Dark theme. I've tried reproducing your issue below on JupyterLab 1.1.3:

[JupyterLab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmi38.png)

Comment: So did you get the str_view() function to work, or did you get the same failed output similar to my own output?